# CircleCI api invalid build parameters

Tags: rest, curl, post, circleci

I'm trying to trigger builds by the CircleCI api and pass some build parameters

```
curl --user ${CIRCLE_TOKEN}: \
    --request POST \
    --form revision=xxx\
    --form config=@config.yml \
    --form notify=false \
    --form build_parameters={key=value} \
        https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/bitbucket/project/repo/tree/master
```

but keep getting the error:

```
{
  "message" : "Invalid build_parameters value: must be a map"
}
```

whats the correct way of sending a map in cURL?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the CircleCI Doc and sent it a JSON body: https://circleci.com/docs/api/v1-reference/#new-build

Also, the build parameter you have in your question is just an example I assume?